# What is titanium in the example on fitting a Gaussian model?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, gaussian

In [the documentation on `fit`](https://mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html), the Gaussian model was created by:

```
[x,y] = titanium;
f = fit(x.',y.','gauss2');
plot(f,x,y)
```

I was wondering what is `titanium`? I can't find any relevant explanation to this topic. My questions are what is titanium and what data does it hold?

Comment: You can always type `help titanium` in MATLAB to get some information on the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a build-in example for this purpose:

```
which titanium
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\toolbox\curvefit\splines\titanium.m

[x,y] titanium; % both 1x49 vectors
plot(x,y,'o')
```

This is the image of the data:

[image]

Basically it's an arbitrary example data set for demonstrating the use of e.g. the Gaussian `fit`. When using the `fit` function, you'll use your own data for `x` and `y` of course, but to get a meaningful example it has been chosen not to use `x=rand(1,49)`, but rather a curve.

It has its own [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/curvefit/titanium.html), thanks to [Cris Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52924111/what-is-titanium-in-gaussian-model/52924315?noredirect=1#comment92758024_52924315) for pointing that out, which states it is a standard test set first used in the paper C. de Boor and J. R. Rice. "Least squares cubic spline approximation II - Variable knots." CSD TR 21, Comp.Sci., Purdue Univ., April 1968. It depicts some property of titanium as a function of temperature.

Comment: [The doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/titanium.html) explains what its is. Apparently it's a standard test set since its use in some paper from 1968.

Comment: If I want to make an input to this gaussian model, does that mean I have to make it as a vector of 1xn? I've been trying to make an output (even a vector of 1x49 and I'm still getting "too many output arguments" message.

Comment: @hphys If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. This to make searching SO easier, and to prevent ephemeral comments from containing significant knowledge.